# How do I change the data type of a calculated attribute in DML with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, ddl, dml

Knowing that SQL Data Definition Language (DDL) Server Postgres (SP) can be used:

- CREATE
- **ALTER**
- DROP

And for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) SP:

- SELECT
- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE

When we make a `SELECT` the attributes that we project come in its type of data established in the DDL. And when performing an operation with 2 attributes of the same type to generate an attribute calculated in a `SELECT`, the type will be the same as that of the operands but I need to change it.

My problem is that I want to calculate an average: **A / B * 100** between two types of data `bigint` but when I do A/B I obtain in the calculated field a 0, because I would need the decimal values also to multiply them by 100

The following sql instruction does not work with `bigint`:

```
SELECT id, a/b
FROM <mytable>;
```

This in the calculated field returns 0 values to me and is what I want to avoid.

And what I would like to have is:

```
SELECT id, first_operand * 100
FROM    (SELECT id, a/b TYPE <newtype> AS first_operand
        FROM <mytable>) firstTable
NATURAL JOIN <mytable>;
```

So what I would like to know is how to change the type of data in a `SELECT` projection or what way do I have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres you can easily [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) by appending `::<type to cast to>` to an expression. So in your case you can try `a::decimal / b::decimal` to have the result of `a / b` being a `decimal`. (Actually already casting only one operand would be enough here, if you like it less verbose.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do typecasting using:

```
cast function i.e. CAST ( expression AS type )
```

or also:

```
PostgreSQL type cast ::  i.e. expression::type
```